# Yaml file saving things in incosistent format with extra curly brakets `{ }`

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to save content using yaml files but I get that in my local computer it saves it in one format and in server/cluster saves it in another format. In the clust

In the cluster it seems strage:

```
{seconds: 56.40548229217529}
{minutes: 0.940091371536255}
{hours: 0.015668189525604248}
{days: 6.528412302335103e-04}
```

but locally it looks fine:

```
seconds: 3.597913980484009
minutes: 0.05996523300806681
hours: 0.0009994205501344469
days: 4.164252292226862e-05
```

Why are those extra parenthesis being inserted?

The code I am using:

```
    with open(meta_data_path, "w") as conffile:
        seconds = hours*60.0*60.0
        minutes = hours*60.0
        days = hours/24.0
        seconds = f'seconds: {seconds}'
        minutes = f'minutes: {minutes}'
        hours = f'hours: {hours}'
        days = f'days: {days}'
        yaml.dump(yaml.load(str(seconds), Loader=Loader), conffile)
        yaml.dump(yaml.load(str(minutes), Loader=Loader), conffile)
        yaml.dump(yaml.load(str(hours), Loader=Loader), conffile)
        yaml.dump(yaml.load(str(days), Loader=Loader), conffile)
```

is there something wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is something wrong with this, as you are writing four YAML documents to the same file, without separating them using `---`.

You should either add the `explicit_start=True` parameter to each `dump()` to get:

```
---
{seconds: 56.40548229217529}
---
{minutes: 0.940091371536255}
---
{hours: 0.015668189525604248}
---
{days: 6.528412302335103e-04}
```

resp:

```
---
seconds: 3.597913980484009
---
minutes: 0.05996523300806681
---
hours: 0.0009994205501344469
---
days: 4.164252292226862e-05
```

Which look different but load the same (using `load_all()`).

Or, you change your code to load all the strings into a single data structure and dump these out in one go:

```
    data = {}
    data.update(yaml.load(str(seconds), Loader=Loader))
    data.update(yaml.load(str(minutes), Loader=Loader))
    data.update(yaml.load(str(hours), Loader=Loader))
    data.update(yaml.load(str(days), Loader=Loader))
    yaml.dump(data, conffile)
```

Which will give you the same result as before locally, and

```
{seconds: 56.40548229217529, minutes: 0.940091371536255, hours: 0.015668189525604248, days: 6.528412302335103e-04}
```

on the server, which is again equivalent YAML.

The reason for the difference is that in older (pre 5.1) PyYAML versions the default for 'default_flow_style' parameter to `dump()` was `None`, resulting in leaf collection nodes being dumped in flow-style, for mappings/dicts this causes the curly braces). For 5.1+ the default changed to `False` and that causes all collections to be block style. So you have a 5.1+ version locally and an old PyYAML on your cluster.

To make them work the same, either install the same PyYAML version on both platforms and/or explicitly add `default_flow_style=False` to your `dump()`.

Comment: Of course you should ask yourself as well why you would want to use PyYAML that only (partly) supports YAML 1.1, which was outdated ten years ago.

Comment: What version of yaml should I be using?